# jQuery Mobile and Rails RESTful actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with how jQuery mobile works with RESTful actions in Rails.

For this explaination, let's assume I have a resource called `Planet` and a `PlanetsController` and I'm attempting to create a new `Planet` by sending a post request from `/planets/new` to `/planets`. If this action succeeds, my URL is now `/planets` even though it's actually showing `/planets/1`. If the action failed, my URL is also now `/planets/` instead of `/planets/new`.

In both of these cases, if I click the Back button to go back to the index action, it won't work because jQuery Mobile thinks I'm already on `/planets`. I have to reload the page in order to get back.

Is there a way to fix this so normal Rails RESTful actions can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as well, I just added data-ajax = "false" to my form with the downside of having no transitions. Or you can follow another solution I found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/jquery-mobile-and-rails.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1